# Custom maps/coordinates

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, maps

I'm looking for a quick way to drop in a map for something like Minecraft into a pan/zoomable thing, with support for custom coordinates (like defining where is 0,0 or something)

Can't seem to figure this out with google maps, any ideas? I have tile pngs for multiple zoomlevels, I have coordinates, just no clue how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to get the look and feel of a map.

### One huge graphic

In case you've got only one huge picture of the map that is maybe even over 100 MB in size, use the service [Zoom.it](http://zoom.it/). Although it's supported by Microsoft and therefore uses Silverlight (JavaScript support available as well, though), it's a handy service. Besides, the homepage also stores the automatically generated tiles and hence serves as a webhoster as well.

### Several tiles at different zoom levels

In this case it's probably best to use the [Google Maps JavaScript API V3](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/). It helps you realise all your map plans. In your case you'd have to overlay your map on the real world map. To be honest, that does sound weird as all coordinates on your specific map are also related to a region on the map of our beloved planet Earth. However, it works like a charm. Should you need webspace to upload your huge map in advance, use a service like [Wuala](http://www.wuala.com/) for this purpose.

### All-in-one Map Generator

As you want to create a map of your Minecraft world, it's maybe best to directly use [Tectonicus](http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?f=1022&t=95739), a deep map renderer that also creates all required HTML pages to render your map using the Google Maps API. You can find an example map [here](http://www.triangularpixels.com/Junk/TectonicusTest/map.html).